# Powershell script to rename file based on a value on the 2nd line of the file

Tags: powershell, rename

I am stuck as I am trying to rename a series of files based on what is on the 2nd line, first 4 values of that line for each file.  I have found several examples but none are working for me.  I have been fiddling with this command but I am missing something (or maybe a lot). :)

I have tried the following:

```
Set-Location -Path C:\temp;
Get-ChildItem SAF13000*.csv |
ForEach-Object{
    $oldname = $_.name;
    $newname = "{0}.csv" -f $(Get-Content $oldname | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1);
    Rename-Item -Path $oldname -NewName $newname
}
```

But get these errors:

> ```
> Rename-Item : Illegal characters in path.
> At line:6 char:9
> +         Rename-Item -Path $oldname -NewName $newname
> +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Rename-Item], ArgumentException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
>  
> Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
> At line:6 char:9
> +         Rename-Item -Path $oldname -NewName $newname
> +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\temp\saf1300011.csv:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
> ```

Comment: PS probably still has the file open and you cannot rename a file that is open.  Try copy instead to verify I'm correct.

Comment: Do not read csv files with `Get-Content` but use `Import-Csv` instead. That is why you get errors like **Illegal characters in path**. The second error denotes you are creating naming collisions, so you need to figure out a way to overcome that. Tip: do not try to cram everything in a single line of code because you can't see your own errors like that anymore.

Comment: @jdweng, files still being open does _not_ apply to this question, which is obvious from the code. Also, if that were the problem, the error message would be different.

Comment: Appreciate the help on this. As a FYI, the formatting was changed when I pasted into this chat board as I do use a separate line for each command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a check for illegal characters and if the file with that name already exists.
'-replace' uses RegEx. That expression should remove illegal chars.
the 'while' loop will keep appending a number to the new file name until no file with that name is found.

```
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\SAF13000*.csv
foreach ($file in $allFiles) {
    
    # Get the second line, and check for invalid characters.
    $line = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1
    $line = $line -replace '/[<>:"/\\|?*]/g'
    $newFileName = "$line.csv"

    # If a file with this name already exists, append ' - ($index)' to it.
    $index = 1
    while (Test-Path -Path "C:\temp\$newFileName") {
        $newFileName = "$line - ($index).csv"
        $index++
    }

    Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $newFileName
}
```

I agree with @Theo about using Import-Csv. You're going to have a nice object with expected values, instead of parsing a raw string.

```
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\SAF13000*.csv
foreach ($file in $allFiles) {
    
    # Get the second line, and check for invalid characters.
    $line = (Import-Csv -Path $file.FullName)[1] # Arrays index starts at '0'.
    $line = $line -replace '/[<>:"/\\|?*]/g'
    $newFileName = "$line.csv"

    # If a file with this name already exists, append ' - ($index)' to it.
    $index = 1
    while (Test-Path -Path "C:\temp\$newFileName") {
        $newFileName = "$line - ($index).csv"
        $index++
    }

    Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $newFileName
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @UncleCisco!  I was able to get this to work like I wanted.  Appreicate the assist!